# How to versioning with ORMLite ? Rename column and table, Insert

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

Actually I don't use ORMLite but I wan't to integrate it, but how to manage the versionning, for exemple I do this:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    if (oldVersion < 4) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + "demandes" + " RENAME TO demandes2");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + "demandes" + "(" + "id" + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + "xmlSendLead" + " TEXT," + "statutEnvoieSendLead" + " INTEGER," + "dateEnvoieSendLead" + " DATETIME," + "contactWebId" + " INTEGER," + "xmlSimulation" + " TEXT," + "statutEnvoieSimulation" + " INTEGER," + "dateEnvoieSimulation" + " DATETIME" + ")");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + "demandes" + " (" + "id" + "," + "xmlSendLead" + "," + "statutEnvoieSendLead" + "," + "dateEnvoieSendLead" + ")" + " SELECT id, xml, statutEnvoie, dateEnvoie" + " FROM demandes2;");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE demandes2");
        System.out.println("v4 parsed");
    }
    if (oldVersion < 5) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + "leads" + "(" + "id" + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + "xmlSendLead" + " TEXT," + "statutSendLead" + " INTEGER," + "dateSendLead" + " DATETIME," + "contactWebId" + " INTEGER," + "xmlSimulation" + " TEXT," + "statutSendSimulation" + " INTEGER," + "dateSendSimulation" + " DATETIME" + ")");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + "leads" + " (" + "id" + "," + "xmlSendLead" + "," + "statutSendLead" + "," + "dateSendLead" + "contactWebId" + "," + "xmlSimulation" + "," + "statutSendSimulation" + "," + "dateSendSimulation" + ")" + " SELECT id, xml, statutEnvoie, dateEnvoie" + " FROM demandes2;");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + "leads" + "(" + "id" + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + "prepaymentPenaltyPercentage" + " REAL," + "notaryFeeGrid" + " INTEGER," + "immoRatePercentage" + " REAL," + "immoMinMonthly" + " INTEGER," + "immoMaxMonthly" + " INTEGER," + "fileFeePercentage" + " REAL," + "date" + " DATETIME," + "consoRatePercentage" + " REAL," + "consoMinMonthly" + " INTEGER," + "consoMaxMonthly" + " INTEGER," + "bankFeePercentage" + " REAL)");
    }
}
```

Do not care about string concatenation please, How to rename table/column or insert data between two tables ?

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand your post.  What is not working about your `onUpgrade(...)` method?  Looks like it is inserting data from one table into another table.  That fails?

Comment: @Gray I'm just thinking about a big database, how we could manage a big database with this method

Comment: I think that your code here would work for any sized database.  Can you flesh out your question some more?

Comment: @Gray If they where a lot of versionning and constants value for each versions how it could be clearfull organized and easy to manage... now I'm gonna use ORMLite and it look pretty easier with

Comment: I think that the code you posted is about as good as you can get @Ben.  There are other projects that try to do it for you but I'm not sure how easy they are to use.